# Researching the irrationality of a number

Tags: nt.number-theory, irrational-numbers

I am conducting a little research on checking if a number, written in positional numeral system is irrational.

Let $h^p_n$ be the most right non-zero digit of number $n!$ written in numeral system with base $p$. For example, in system with base $10$, $8!=40320\Rightarrow h_8^{10}=2.$ The question is following: for which $p$ number $H^p=0,h^p_1h^p_2\ldots h^p_n\ldots$ is irrational?

Obviously, $H^2$ is rational. I also know that $H^{10}$ is irrational,  but have no idea on how to prove it and would really appreciate any kind of hint.

Comment: There are [recursive formulas](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130352/last-non-zero-digit-of-a-factorial) for this rightmost nonzero digit. These recursive formulas can probably be used to show that the sequence is not periodic, hence this number will be irrational.

Comment: Have you seen http://home.wlu.edu/~dresdeng/papers/two.pdf ?

Comment: These formulas don't seem really helpful, because the use "greatest integer function", which complicates the analysis. But thanks a lot, I will examine it to see, if anything can be done here.

Comment: @so-calledfriendDon, that's a great thing,  thank you. At first look, this proof heavily uses that $p=10$.

Comment: If $p$ is prime (so $(p-1)!=-1\pmod{p}$) and $n=\sum_id_ip^i$ in base $p$ then it works out that $h^p_n=\pm\prod_id_i!\pmod{p}$, and this is not periodic even if we ignore the $\pm$ signs.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Very interesting, but can you give some explanation on how you figured out that $h_n^p=\pm\prod_i d_i! \pmod p$ and why is it not periodic?

Comment: Were it periodic with period $a = p^e b$ with $(b,p)=1$, by multiplying $b$ suitably (since it divides some $p^f - 1$), wlog $b = p^f - 1$, i.e. $a = p^{e+f} - p^e$, i.e. in base $p$ $a$ is a string of $(p-1)$'s followed by a string of $0$'s. Now take $n = 2p^{e+f-1}$, which has base $p$ digits $(0,2,0,\ldots,0,0,\ldots,0)$, and compare $h_n^p$ with the same for $n+a$, which has base $p$ digits $(1,1,p-1,\ldots,p-1,0,\ldots,0)$. One gets that $2! = 2\equiv \pm 1\pmod{p}$, which is false once $p>3$.

Comment: As for the formula given for $h_n^p$, use the multinomial Lucas theorem on the decomposition of $n = \underbrace{1 + \cdots + 1}_{d_0} + \cdots + \underbrace{p^i + \cdots + p^i}_{d_i} + \cdots$ to get $h_n^p\equiv \prod d_i! \cdot \prod (h_{p^i}^p)^{n_i} \pmod{p}$. Since $h_{p^i}^p = h_{p^i - 1}^p$ it follows by induction on $i$ that $h_{p^i}^p = \pm 1$! Lemme know if I've made a mistake in the above!

Comment: How, Michael, can you know $H^{10}$ is irrational, if you have no idea how to prove it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have encountered this fact somewhere.